# pmap shows mappings of "other objects" - how do I find out what these are?

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, ebpf, rust, pmap

I am investigating some sort of a memory leak in my rust application. The memory keeps growing at a steady pace (starts at around 30M and grows 50M per day). The application is written in rust and it pretty much just attaches an XDP/BPF program to a few interfaces and reads some data via BPF maps and publishes some metrics.

Interestingly, the "leak" is only occurring in our test environment (memory usage is very stable in production so far).

Below is some pmap output (I have filtered out `*.so` and `anon_inode:[perf_event]` as there are quite a few and they are not part of the issue).

Looking at this it seems that my leak is not on the heap (so no point in analyzing the heap). I want to understand what the unnamed mappings to other objects are as they seem to be growing (see `>>>`).

Any ideas or tools I can use to figure out what is taking up this memory?

```
         Address Perm   Offset Device   Inode   Size    Rss    Pss Referenced Anonymous LazyFree ShmemPmdMapped FilePmdMapped Shared_Hugetlb Private_Hugetlb Swap SwapPss Locked THPeligible Mapping
    55f8470e2000 r-xp 00000000  fd:04 3145822   5820   4472   4472       4468         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 my-program-name
    55f847891000 r--p 005af000  fd:04 3145822    368    368    368        368       368        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 my-program-name
    55f8478ed000 rw-p 0060b000  fd:04 3145822     12     12     12         12        12        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 my-program-name
    55f848a15000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0    132    108    108        108       108        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [heap]
>>> 7f14f8000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  24140  20620  20620      20620     20620        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f14f9793000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0  41396      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1500000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0    132     12     12         12        12        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1500021000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0  65404      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
>>> 7f1504000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  55792  47976  47976      47976     47976        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f150767c000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0   9744      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1508000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  65496  52136  52136      52080     52136        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f150bff6000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0     40      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f150c000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0    132     36     36         36        36        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f150c021000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0  65404      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1510000000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0  65484  62776  62776      62776     62776        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1513ff3000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0     52      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f15172de000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f15172df000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0   2048     20     20         20        20        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f15176f3000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0      8      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b0a000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     24      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b13000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b14000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0      8      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b16000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b17000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0      8      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b19000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517b1a000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0   2048     20     20         20        20        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517eeb000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1517eec000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0   2048     56     56         56        56        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f15180ec000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f15180ed000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0   2048     56     56         56        56        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1518696000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     16     16     16         16        16        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1518df8000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     16      4      4          4         4        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519665000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     12     12     12         12        12        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519ae1000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519ae2000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     28     16     16         16        16        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519ae9000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519aea000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0      8      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519aec000 ---p 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519aed000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0     16      8      8          8         8        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7f1519af3000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0      4      4      4          4         4        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 
    7ffd52d94000 rw-p 00000000  00:00       0    132     32     32         32        32        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [stack]
    7ffd52ddd000 r--p 00000000  00:00       0     12      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [vvar]
    7ffd52de0000 r-xp 00000000  00:00       0      8      4      0          4         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [vdso]
ffffffffff600000 r-xp 00000000  00:00       0      4      0      0          0         0        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 [vsyscall]
                                              ====== ====== ====== ========== ========= ======== ============== ============= ============== =============== ==== ======= ====== =========== 
                                              455904 193740 191239     193668    184644        0              0             0              0               0    0       0      0           0 KB
```